# custom formtype wraps ArrayCollection in ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I have a ManyToMany Relation (*AdditionalCostTemplate>Accommodation*) and i have a custom formtype extending EntityType to fill the Accommodations in my AdditionalCostTemplate.

If i use the default symfony2 [`EntityType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) Formtype, it all works well.
If i use my custom EntityType it wraps my Accommodation Entities in an additional [`ArrayCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html).
Now i stripped my custom entity to just having a different name, nothing else.
The error still appears.

My Annotations:

```
/**
 * AdditionalCostTemplate
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AdditionalCostTemplate
{
    /**
     * @var PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\AccommodationBundle\Entity\Accommodation", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $accommodations;
    [...]
```

My Entity FormType:

```
class CallbackEntityType extends EntityType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_callback_entity_type';
    }
}
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but could it be because you're both extending the `entity` type and defining it as `parent`?

Try replacing the `extends EntityType` with `extends AbstractType`...

Comment: I am also "not sure" why that causes the Problem but it DID cause the Problem. Thanks a lot!